# Is there a service that detects if a javascript library is browser dependent?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to the whole javascript ecosystem and I was wondering if there is a service that allows you to analyze a javascript library and determine whether it depends on browser apis. For the sake of simplicity, let's consider only the top 3 browser on the market. I know going through the dependencies of each library individually is a way to go, but brute force is something I wish to omit.

Comment: I'd expect any dependencies to be mentioned in the library's documentation.

Comment: Fair enough...still, is there a service that does that for you or should I create a tool that analyzes the dependencies of a particular js library?

Comment: There might be, but requests for third-party services like this are off-topic here.

Comment: Where should I submit my question then?

Answer (score 4):

You can check Can I use. It allows you to determine if this is integrated

http://caniuse.com/#search=promises